# What is a reliable measure of closeness to singularity for a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, svd, singularity

Assume I have a problem where the solution is a singular matrix. I am given several matrices that are all pretty close to each other (i.e. the element-by-element differences are small) and I'm trying to choose the one that is closest to singularity. In reality, my perfect solution would have been singular and I am trying to find the one closest to it.

What is the best way to measure this? I know comparing the determinants is not a good idea. I thought the condition number would be a good measure, but when I tried it out on an example set of matrices (where the determinant of one was an absolute zero) and the one with the largest condition number did not end end up with the largest condition number.

I'm suspecting the reason the condition number is not giving me a good measure is round off errors in the singular values. So is there any better way to figure this out?

**EDIT** - In case anyone is interested in the problem I'm working on. I'm using Cayley-Menger determinants. The determinant being zero would indicate that the matrix is a *distance matrix*.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this area enough to comment on the reliability of any such measure, but a popular one is $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$ using any matrix norm you like.

Comment: @user1551 yeah I've tried that as well. For my case it seems to work pretty similar to the condition number (slightly better). It won't choose the closest one though.

Comment: Have you tried using the least singular value?

Comment: @Hadi *"It won't choose the closest one though."* Hmm, what do you mean ? To find "the closest one", you need some sort of measure, but you haven't one yet, have you?!

Comment: @user1551 I have not tried using the least singular value. I'll try that. What I mean by "the closest one" is the one which has a determinant of zero. I intentionally compare the other ones with one which has a determinant that is an absolute zero to see if it will choose that one.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Gaussian Elimination with Complete Pivoting (GECP). If the matrix is singular, eventually the infinity norm of the remaining residual matrix will be less than some user-specified tolerance. If the user-specified tolerance is reduced, the matrix rank may decrease. Applying GECP to all matrices and successively reducing the user-specified tolerance, the surviving matrix with the lowest rank would be the winner.

Warning. A matrix gets the rank it deserves. If a matrix's entries are noisy or inaccurately evaluated, the noise and/or inaccuracies may dominate the residual matrix and fuzzy up the matrix rank determination process.